# SQL: extract some records from table_A, then insert to table_B

Tags: sql, impala

I need to extract some records from table_A, and then insert these records to table_B. I have the following pseudo code:

```
insert into table_B (select * from table_A)
```

I am wondering what would be the correct syntax for the above pseudo code? Thanks!

Comment: if there is a identity seeded column then you have to specify the fields... insert into tableB (fields1....) select fields1.. from tableA .. if none then your query should just work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the tables have matching set of columns, you can do:

```
insert into table_b select * from table_a;
```

If table_b has only a subset of columns of table_a, select them manually like:

```
insert into table_b (col1, col2, col3, . . ., colN)
select col1, col2, col3, . . ., colN from table_a;
```